# I am unable to render components dynamically in react.js,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, render

So, I started working in react and got stuck, when I was trying to render a component dynamically into the view, from a JSON file online. I am using axios.get to get information from JSON but is unable to render it properly.

any help is highly appreciated!!

Json : [Json Link used in the project](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axyok)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class Lessons extends Component {
  state = {
    Questions: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: Questions } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axyok"
    );
    this.setState({ Questions });
    console.log(Questions);
    console.log(this.state.Questions.QuestionID);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h4 style={{ padding: "20px" }}>{this.state.Questions.QuestionID}</h4>
    );
  }
}
```

The value for this.state.Questions.QuestionID (an example) is not getting rendered into the view

the part where it was supposed to render (below the question) QuestionID is blank[check screenshot of the project here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHHnq.png)

So i tried to make two logs in the console (check code) and got the following output. The console.log for the object => console.log(Questions) gives result. another one, shows undefined
[check image of console.log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWbNY.png)

Comment: setState is asynchronous, that's why your console.log yields undefined. Use a second argument to setState with a callback when you need to access the state.

Comment: `Questions` is an array. Therefore it doesn't have a property `QuestionID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Questions` is an array with one element in it, so you want to get element `0` of the array before trying to access `QuestionId`. The `Questions` is also a property of the response object, so you need to use that and not just the `data`.

**Example**

```
class Lessons extends Component {
  state = {
    Questions: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axyok"
    );
    this.setState({ Questions: data.Questions });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h4 style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        {this.state.Questions[0] && this.state.Questions[0].QuestionID}
      </h4>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because axios's `response.data` contains the raw JSON data. Now with the JSON you posted the object contains an Array `Question` and each items in the Array contains the `QuestionID`. So modify the component code to this

```
class Lessons extends Component {
  state = {
    Questions: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: Questions } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axyok"
    );
    this.setState({ Questions: Questions.Questions }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.Questions);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.Questions.map((each) => (
      <h4 style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        {each.QuestionID}
      </h4>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Aadi! but it shows an error that 'each' is not defined!